# Error testing In-app billing sample - Dungeons

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to get the in-app billing sample Dungeons, I have a draft application with my public-id, and I have published unmanaged item potion_001. I use same google-account on device as registered merchant-account.

Static test works fine but when trying to buy the potion I get:

```
DEBUG/vending(1437): [1] BaseBuyPageActivity.onPostResponse(): {PurchaseResult=ERROR_GAIA_AUTH, PurchaseInfo=PurchaseInfo=, SignupStatus=NEW_USER, TId=null, ShoppingCart=null, RefundPolicy=[], ErrorFields=[]}
DEBUG/vending(1437): [1] BaseBuyPageActivity.onPostResponse(): Invalid checkout token: { /.../ }
DEBUG/vending(1437): [1] BaseBuyPageActivity.onPostResponse(): {PurchaseResult=OK, PurchaseInfo=PurchaseInfo=, SignupStatus=SIGNED_UP, TId=300449045376486, ShoppingCart=[ItemPrice=7,00 kr, TaxInclusive=, TaxExclusive=, Total=7,00 kr, HasTaxMessage=false, TaxMessage=null, HasFooterMessage=false, FooterMessage=null], RefundPolicy=<b>Ingen återbetalning.</b><br/><a href="http://market.android.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=1061913">Info</a><br/><a href="http://www.google.com/mobile/android/fsa-notification.html">Reglerat av FSA, UK</a>, Instruments=[[Id=724253266825206, Name=VISA xxx-xxxx Invalid=false Type=CREDIT_CARD] ], DefaultBillingInstrument=724253266825206, ErrorFields=[]}
DEBUG/vending(1437): [1] BaseBuyPageActivity.shouldAddCarrierBilling(): isProvisioned(): false isSavedonServer(): false radio available? true
DEBUG/vending(1437): [1] BaseBuyPageActivity.shouldAddCarrierBilling(): isProvisioned(): false isSavedonServer(): false radio available? true
DEBUG/vending(1437): [200] BaseAction.run(): ApiException: com.android.vending.api.ApiException: Error from backend. Request=com.android.vending.model.PurchaseOrderRequest, Response=INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR
DEBUG/vending(1437): [1] LocalAssetDatabase.notifyListener(): inapp:com.package.billingtest:potion_001 / UNINSTALLED
DEBUG/vending(1437): [1] LocalAssetCache.updateOneAsset(): No local info for inapp:com.package.billingtest:potion_001    
INFO/vending(1437): [1] BaseAction.displayErrorUi(): Server error in com.android.vending.billing.PurchaseOrderAction: com.android.vending.api.ApiException: Error from backend. Request=com.android.vending.model.PurchaseOrderRequest, Response=INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR
DEBUG/vending(1437): [1] LocalAssetDatabase.notifyListener(): inapp:se.xebralabs.billingTest:potion_001 / UNINSTALLED
DEBUG/vending(1437): [1] LocalAssetCache.updateOneAsset(): No local info for inapp:com.package.billingtest:potion_001
INFO/vending(1437): [1] BaseAction.displayErrorUi(): Server error in com.android.vending.billing.PurchaseOrderAction: com.android.vending.api.ApiException: Error from backend. Request=com.android.vending.model.PurchaseOrderRequest, Response=INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR
```

(I removed the actual token code in this logcat-snippet)

Any ideas whats goes wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you published the potion-001?

Have you installed the app on your test phone from the same APK as you uploaded to the market? i.e. Put it on your SD cards and manually installed it (Not installed it through eclipse)?

What is the response you are getting back from the Android Market? DEVELOPER_ERROR?

**You cannot test real payments from the SAME GMAIL as the google merchant account is registered to. The same way you can't purchase your own apps. You can't purchase your own inapp items.**

You will need to add a test account to your developer page. Then have a phone sign into the android app market with this account and then test on that phone. n.b. to sign into a new gmail account from your market you have to factory reset the phone :-(

Google Backup:

http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_testing.html

> To test your in-app billing implementation with actual in-app purchases, you will need to register at least one test account on the Android Market publisher site. **You cannot use your developer account to test the complete in-app purchase process because Google Checkout does not let you buy items from yourself**. If you have not set up test accounts before, see [Setting up test accounts](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_admin.html#billing-testing-setup).

Comment: It is true, that I tested with same gmail account. I'm currently trying to get this tested with another account. I have some issues not having the latest market on my other phone - and adb not recognizing the device working properly.. I will come back to this question with feedback when tested.

Comment: Verified - purchase was successful from another account.

Comment: in-app billing is really giving me hard time. I have been working on it from 2 days and still can't get it... :@

Comment: If you need a second look here's a different tutorial from android.dev's Tried to simplify it a little: http://www.anddev.org/advanced-tutorials-f21/simple-inapp-billing-payment-t52060.html

Comment: Hello @Blundell i had used the tutorial given in the adk & follow the steps as mention in the http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_testing.html I had make the product list ,make testaccount, & upload the apk But when i download it.It doesn't show me the products & their prices which i had alredy enterd Why So, Can you help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance....