# Will I need two phones to develop android apps?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

Regarding this question
[Error testing In-app billing sample - Dungeons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501370/error-testing-in-app-billing-sample-dungeons)

This, more or less implies, that painless android development of paid apps- and in-app purchases require two phones? Am I correct?

Comment: From your link, it appears you can factory reset your phone and use a different Google account to test a purchase.

Comment: That is not acceptable, as i Use my phone for day-to-day use as well. But thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more phones, the better. But if you have only one phone, you can always reset it to factory settings and change google account.

Comment: This means that the only reasonable thing to do, is to get a phone number two.

Comment: If your device isn't for development only, then yes.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the emulator mimics a mobile device but I wouldn't deploy anything without testing it on at least 1 real phone.  With all the fragmentation that exists with Android I'm sure most top-quality apps are tested on a wide variety of devices.

When considering google accounts, keep in mind that many people have multiple gmail/google accounts on a single phone.

Comment: I have a Nexus one with Stock Android 2.3.3

Are you sure that people have multiple accounts on a single phone? I was not aware that you could have more than one Checkout-profile at the same time?

Comment: Glenn, I'm not familiar with the Checkout API but you can certainly have multiple gmail/google accounts on a single device. In Java, you can access them via [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html).