# OpenGL losing surface after in-app billing is activated

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-intent, andengine, in-app-billing

This is a derivative question of a question I have posted here:
[In App BIlling trouble with Pending Intents and switching activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352150/in-app-billing-trouble-with-pending-intents-and-switching-activities)

The problem I have now is directly related to all of the information on that question but most likely deals with a completely different topic (OpenGL) and is therefore in need of this new question.  But please refer to the code posted there for your information.

The basic problem is this:

I have an Andengine game with google's in-app-billing.  When the user clicks the "buy" button, you get a nifty little popup from the Marketplace that deals with your transaction.  This popup works great, when the user gives the proper credit card info they are charged for the transaction and I get some money.  Sadly, upon completing a transaction (completing in this case either means charging it or deciding not to buy it, either way they complete the action as far as the Market popup is concerned) they are brought to a black screen that stays black until the game times out or they force quit it.

By analyzing the LogCat, I believe I have narrowed the problem down to the OpenGL surface behind my Andengine activity being lost and the game therefore being unable to load any of the relevant resources.   I don't know anything about OpenGL so I have no idea how to fix this.  All I want is for the simple Andengine activity to resume or restart after the pendingintent launched by the in-app billing has done its business.  This is what I believe is causing the error although the full LogCat dump is in the question linked above:

```
06-16 11:20:23.635: DEBUG/dalvikvm(3807): GC_EXPLICIT freed 53K, 45% free 3710K/6663K, external 1K/513K, paused 102ms
06-16 11:20:23.885: ERROR/Surface(3807): surface (identity=158) is invalid, err=-19 (No such device)
06-16 11:20:23.905: ERROR/Surface(3807): surface (identity=158) is invalid, err=-19 (No such device)
06-16 11:20:23.905: ERROR/Surface(3807): surface (identity=158) is invalid, err=-19 (No such device)
06-16 11:20:23.905: ERROR/Adreno200-EGL(3807): egliSwapWindowSurface: unable to dequeue native buffer
```

Please let me know if you can help, most likely you will need experience with OpenGL on Android and preferably a basic knowledge of Andengine (or at least how it works with OpenGL).   I'm not doing anything too complicated with the graphics so that's not an issue, the screen that I wish to resume (my "Store Front") consists of nothing more than various sprites and a minimal amount of text.

Thanks

Comment: You might have better luck asking the AndEngine developers directly.  I use GLSurface with the android billing API with no issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was answered in the linked question after all, sorry for even posting this question (I just thought it might be a totally new issue).

see: [In App BIlling trouble with Pending Intents and switching activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352150/in-app-billing-trouble-with-pending-intents-and-switching-activities)